# toggle of navbar-collapse from bootstrap's own site is not replicable

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to better understand Bootstrap by recreating '[the Company](http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_theme_company.asp#services)' theme. The problem I'm having is that I can't get the navbar-collapse to function properly. The toggle is created but clicking on doesn't reposition the menu items and it basically has no effect.

I'm pretty sure this is an issue with Jquery because when I take out that section from the 'try it out' section it breaks as expected. It works on the w3schools site just not on codepen.

Unfortunately, that doesn't really help me and I don't know if this is a conflict with codepen or if I have messed something up. I do know that even when I copy it directly something is still wrong.

I've a codepen [here](http://codepen.io/hrokr/pen/grWEKN) with the relevant copy/pasted code as an example but it's also written below. Again, is straight from W3schools.

```
 <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>                        
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#myPage">Logo</a>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#about">ABOUT</a></li>
        <li><a href="#services">SERVICES</a></li>
        <li><a href="#portfolio">PORTFOLIO</a></li>
        <li><a href="#pricing">PRICING</a></li>
        <li><a href="#contact">CONTACT</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

The only CSS I have for this abbreviated example is:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    .col-sm-4 {
      text-align: center;
      margin: 25px 0;
    }
  }
```

Thanks for the help, after two days on this I don't have any other ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The markup is correct, but the problem is that the CodePen doesn't include `bootstrap.js`. The JS is needed for Bootstrap to recognize the `data-toggle="collapse"` attribute.

http://www.bootply.com/XZKwzaHKut

Comment: That did it. Thanks very much. I would up vote this but I don't have the reputation required to.

Answer (score 0):

Add the Bootstrap JS to the codepen and it should work for you.

Comment: That was it. Thanks very much.